New Input System and Touch Ended / Pen Lifted / Mouse Up
How does one use the new input system to determine the states:

Touch Ended
Pen Lifted
Mouse Up

I've tried subscribing to canceled (isn't always triggered, seems to false trigger). There does not seem to be an ended?
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputEndDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool hasInputEnded = false;
    private PlayerControls playerControls;
    private InputAction pointerAction;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();
        pointerAction = playerControls.NewActionMap.Pointer;
        pointerAction.canceled += OnPointerEnded; // Listen for the canceled event
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        pointerAction.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        pointerAction.Disable();
    }

    private void OnPointerEnded(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.canceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Pointer lifted or ended");
            hasInputEnded = true;
        }
    }

    public static bool HasInputEnded()
    {
        bool x = hasInputEnded;
        hasInputEnded = false;
        return x;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was auto-generated by com.unity.inputsystem:InputActionCodeGenerator
//     version 1.7.0
//     from Assets/Core/Input/PlayerControls.inputactions
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities;

public partial class @PlayerControls: IInputActionCollection2, IDisposable
{
    public InputActionAsset asset { get; }
    public @PlayerControls()
    {
        asset = InputActionAsset.FromJson(@"{
    ""name"": ""PlayerControls"",
    ""maps"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""NewActionMap"",
            ""id"": ""4075ce87-7790-4f43-bafa-e80dea298f8d"",
            ""actions"": [
                {
                    ""name"": ""Pointer"",
                    ""type"": ""Button"",
                    ""id"": ""9ae9dda6-f644-4e18-992e-4ef4f0712423"",
                    ""expectedControlType"": ""Button"",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""initialStateCheck"": false
                }
            ],
            ""bindings"": [
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""dab7977f-e958-40fc-94cc-7d4fa6f90a65"",
                    ""path"": ""Pen/PenContact"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": """",
                    ""action"": ""Pointer"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""dbdbf34f-3af8-43f3-beab-67112bb1771d"",
                    ""path"": ""Touchscreen/primaryTouch/press"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": """",
                    ""action"": ""Pointer"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""1dd51653-af24-4e16-bd45-5ec5e8cef172"",
                    ""path"": ""Mouse/leftButton"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": """",
                    ""action"": ""Pointer"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""98ff3390-6756-4307-bba5-44364121b1b6"",
                    ""path"": ""*/{PrimaryAction}"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": """",
                    ""action"": ""Pointer"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ""controlSchemes"": []
}");
        // NewActionMap
        m_NewActionMap = asset.FindActionMap("NewActionMap", throwIfNotFound: true);
        m_NewActionMap_Pointer = m_NewActionMap.FindAction("Pointer", throwIfNotFound: true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(asset);
    }

    public InputBinding? bindingMask
    {
        get => asset.bindingMask;
        set => asset.bindingMask = value;
    }

    public ReadOnlyArray<InputDevice>? devices
    {
        get => asset.devices;
        set => asset.devices = value;
    }

    public ReadOnlyArray<InputControlScheme> controlSchemes => asset.controlSchemes;

    public bool Contains(InputAction action)
    {
        return asset.Contains(action);
    }

    public IEnumerator<InputAction> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return asset.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Enable()
    {
        asset.Enable();
    }

    public void Disable()
    {
        asset.Disable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<InputBinding> bindings => asset.bindings;

    public InputAction FindAction(string actionNameOrId, bool throwIfNotFound = false)
    {
        return asset.FindAction(actionNameOrId, throwIfNotFound);
    }

    public int FindBinding(InputBinding bindingMask, out InputAction action)
    {
        return asset.FindBinding(bindingMask, out action);
    }

    // NewActionMap
    private readonly InputActionMap m_NewActionMap;
    private List<INewActionMapActions> m_NewActionMapActionsCallbackInterfaces = new List<INewActionMapActions>();
    private readonly InputAction m_NewActionMap_Pointer;
    public struct NewActionMapActions
    {
        private @PlayerControls m_Wrapper;
        public NewActionMapActions(@PlayerControls wrapper) { m_Wrapper = wrapper; }
        public InputAction @Pointer => m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMap_Pointer;
        public InputActionMap Get() { return m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMap; }
        public void Enable() { Get().Enable(); }
        public void Disable() { Get().Disable(); }
        public bool enabled => Get().enabled;
        public static implicit operator InputActionMap(NewActionMapActions set) { return set.Get(); }
        public void AddCallbacks(INewActionMapActions instance)
        {
            if (instance == null || m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMapActionsCallbackInterfaces.Contains(instance)) return;
            m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMapActionsCallbackInterfaces.Add(instance);
            @Pointer.started += instance.OnPointer;
            @Pointer.performed += instance.OnPointer;
            @Pointer.canceled += instance.OnPointer;
        }

        private void UnregisterCallbacks(INewActionMapActions instance)
        {
            @Pointer.started -= instance.OnPointer;
            @Pointer.performed -= instance.OnPointer;
            @Pointer.canceled -= instance.OnPointer;
        }

        public void RemoveCallbacks(INewActionMapActions instance)
        {
            if (m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMapActionsCallbackInterfaces.Remove(instance))
                UnregisterCallbacks(instance);
        }

        public void SetCallbacks(INewActionMapActions instance)
        {
            foreach (var item in m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMapActionsCallbackInterfaces)
                UnregisterCallbacks(item);
            m_Wrapper.m_NewActionMapActionsCallbackInterfaces.Clear();
            AddCallbacks(instance);
        }
    }
    public NewActionMapActions @NewActionMap => new NewActionMapActions(this);
    public interface INewActionMapActions
    {
        void OnPointer(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    }
}
```

